# 301 redirect from all pages to main page, without wp-admin directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i need to redirect all pages from my site to main page, and my admin directory must work. For example, page: http://novaya-sergeevka.ru/1, have to redirect to http://novaya-sergeevka.ru/ and the directory /wp-admin/ must work. Thanks

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: sorry, i`m forget to point it. I use nginx/1.2.1